# zsh: bad substitution when trying to install multiple version of R

Tags: r, zsh

I'm trying to install multiple versions of R, and following the steps from https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/.
When I entered `sudo yum install R-${R_4.0.2}-1-1.x86_64.rpm`,
it gave me this error:
`zsh: bad substitution`.
Any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Does `sudo yum install R-4.0.2-1-1.x86_64.rpm` work?

Comment: In that howto, its use of `R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm` is *after* it defines a variable with `export R_VERSION=3.6.3`. So had you followed their hints and done `export R_VERSION=4.0.2` first and then `sudo yum install R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm`, it should have worked. The `${R_VERSION}` is attempting to extract the value of the environment variable `R_VERSION`, which can be set using the `export` command.